# binding functions on alternative click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a plugin to add or down vote a post. I am trying to bind functions on alternative click of the anchor tags.
Here is the html markup

```
<div class="voter">
    <a class="vote_added" data-id="25">Vote Up</a>
    <a class="vote_down" data-id="25">Vote Down</a>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript

```
jQuery(".voter a:first-child").on( "click", function() {

       if(jQuery(this).hasClass('vote_added')){
        console.log("click");
        var data = jQuery(this).data();
        console.log(data);
        votemeaddvote(data.id);
        jQuery(this).removeClass('vote_added');
        jQuery('.voter a:last-child').addClass('vote_down');
       }else{
        jQuery(this).off();
        console.log(" Turning Off --- Vote Up Feature");
       }
    });

    jQuery(".voter a:last-child").on( "click", function() {

       if(jQuery(this).hasClass('vote_down')){
        console.log("click");
        var data = jQuery(this).data();
        console.log(data);
        votemedownvote(data.id);
        jQuery(this).removeClass('vote_down');
        jQuery('.voter a:first-child').addClass('vote_added');
       }else{
        jQuery(this).off();
        console.log(" Turnig Off --- Vote Down Feature");
       }
    });
```

What this code is working only for once because as i am detaching the events using `.off();` function. I want

if i click on add vote feature.

```
1) It should run a function (votemeaddvote(data.id));
2) If i click it again , It should get disable.
```

If i click on Down vote feature.

```
1) It should run a function (votemedownvote(data.id));
2) if i click it again , It should get disable.
3) Add vote function should work if i click on add vote after clicking down vote i.e Vice Versa.
```

It's functionality is quite similar as the voting system in boredpanda.com
I am trying to implement something similar for the front end.

Comment: What exactly is the issue with your current code?

Comment: the issue is when i click on add vote , it works and get disable !! If i click on down vote , It works and get disable !! After these two events none of the button is working . I want if click on ad vote  , down vote should work and if i click on down vote , add vote should work. Check boredpanda.com voting feature.

Comment: There are two function that i am executing on click are ajax based which are responsible for updation of data in the database.

Comment: You are stripping the down_vote and add_vote classes after the initial execution and testing for those classes before executing the upvote/downvote logic.  Why not just add a class like 'voted' and check for the existence of that class?  So if an element has a 'voted' class, it won't vote again.  But if you vote the other direction, it will strip the voted class and apply it to the new vote?  Does that make sense.

Comment: can you explain your logic in code